# Solving octic equation using quadratic formula

Tags: quadratics

According to the wikipedia article on octic equations, octic equations of the form $ax^8 \pm bx^4 \pm c = 0$ can be solved using the quadratic formula. How might one actually do this?

Comment: Substitute $x^4$ by $y$. The equation becomes $ay^2\pm by\pm c=0$

Comment: Solve as a quadratic for $x^4$, then take the square root twice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing $w=x^4$ it's familiar:

$$w = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 \pm 4ac}}{2a}.$$

Then extract the eight roots by taking $v_1 = \sqrt{w}, v_2 = -\sqrt{w}$, and then $x=\pm \sqrt{v_1}$ and $x = \pm \sqrt{v_2}$, for each of the two values of $w$.

Comment: So the values of X will be the positive and negative square roots of U1 and U2?

Comment: Just remember that there are two values of $w$ from the quadratic formula.  You get four roots apiece for each value of $w$, which gives you eight roots (values for $x$).  Some may be repeated roots.  All of the complex roots will come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Oh, so I'd have to get u1 and u2 for one value of w but also u3 and u4 for the other value. Got it, thanks!